# Converting Yamaha EX5 s1s files to MIDI

Tags: midi, synthesizer

the diskette drive on my Yamaha EX5R synth has stopped loading files, even after I replaced the drive. I have the files backed-up but they are the S1S proprietary format. Is there a way to convert them to MIDI? --Thanks much.

Comment: There is librarian software for the EX5 called "ex.factory", which costs €25. You can check the manual here to see whether it does what you need: http://www.xfactory-librarians.co.uk/manuals.html